# ideals in ring of fractions

Tags: ring-theory

Let $S$ be a multiplicative set in a commutative ring $R$ and let $I$ and $J$ be ideals in $R$.  If $S^{-1}I =\{a/s|a\in I, s\in S\}$ is the ring of fractions of $I$, how do you show that $S^{-1}(I\cap J)=S^{-1}I\cap S^{-1} J$?  (This is Theorem 4.7(ii) in Hungerford.)

Comment: Hi: since you're new, please take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) and add to your question. Thanks.

Comment: The inclusion $\subset$ is clear form the definition. Lets take $x\in S^{-1}I\cap S^{-1}J$. Then, there are $s_1,s_2\in S$, $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ such that $x=a/s_1=b/s_2$. Then there is $t\in S$ such that $t(s_2a-s_1b)=0$. Observe that $ts_2a\in I$, but since this is equal to $ts_1b$ it is also in $J$. Now, $x=a/s_1=(ts_2a)/(ts_2s_1)$, which is in $S^{-1}(I\cap J)$.